# git has no "clone" option

Tags: windows-7, git, eclipse

I downloaded **eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64** and selected **Git repository explorer** under **window>open perspective>other** .

Now I trying to do the following as in [this mannual](http://drsaada.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/google-eclipse-egit.html) , at stage 4 it asks to chose **clone** option   , but as I am seen there is no such an option , in other computer I seen that this option is exist   .

I work with **windows 7 Home premium** .

I attach screenshot of this occur -

[image]

What could I do to get this **clone** option ?

Comment: I don't see anything about context menu in that tutorial. Isn't there a "clone" button somewhere? Cloning a repo isn't related to an existing repo, so I wouldn't expect it in the context menu.

Comment: @gronostaj : you right  , its some of these buttons . thanks  .

Answer (score 1):

Clone is the fourth button to the right of the tab labeled "Git Repositories." The GUI you're looking at isn't clearing explaining that the "Git Repositories" view is showing a list of local repositories, which are generally either created empty from scratch or cloned from a remote repository. It isn't a list of remote repositories you could clone from, which is why "clone" isn't on that context menu. (Not that it would be impossible to clone a local repository, it just isn't a common thing to do.)

Answer (score 0):

You can see "`git (NO-HEAD)`" behind your contextual menu.
That is typical of a new git repo without any commit.

Start making at least one commit, and see if the clone option is still missing.

Comment: done . still missing  .

Comment: @URL87 the instruction 4 looks like asking to click on clone, without selecting an existing repo, but to clone a remote repo.